# Views counter is wonky

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The views counter is obviously wonky, I have [one question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/620/donations-do-they-actually-work) with four upvotes and only two views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, <s>two</s>three things:

1. it's based on the IP address, so multiple hits from a single IP don't count -- could be several users from same IP.
2. it is cached and written in batches, to reduce database load. The threshold here is 10 and 5 (meta).
3. during private beta traffic is pretty low, relative to what it is when the site is public. So the views will be quite a bit smaller overall.

edit: I checked in a change to make the views a bit more reliable for some edge conditions, and I reduced the buffering threshold.

Comment: OK, I assumed it was like the voting, but it's not as strict.

Comment: I'm confused about point 2, wouldn't your views only be displayed in increments of 5?  For the record I have the same issue and it seems like a long shot that these points would explain it.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/good-sites-to-request-an-inbound-link-when-launching-a-new-website